# Monitor when Database is created and receive an email

Tags: sql-server

I created a trigger at the level of the server to control when a db is created.

I have this script that was working fine on SQL 2014, now we moved to SQL 2017, the script is working but I receive lot of emails

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ddl_trig_database]
ON ALL SERVER
FOR ALTER_DATABASE
AS

DECLARE @results NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @subjectText NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @databaseName NVARCHAR(255)

SET @subjectText = 'NEW DATABASE Created on ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' by ' + SUSER_SNAME() 

SET @results = (SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)'))
SET @databaseName = (SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)'))

       EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
       @profile_name = 'EmailProfile',
       @recipients = 'test@domain.com',
       @body = @results,
       @subject = @subjectText,
       @exclude_query_output = 1 --Suppress 'Mail Queued' message

GO
```

I receive for example in different emails each of these lines:

```
ALTER DATABASE [testNewDB] SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = DISABLED
ALTER DATABASE [testNewDB] SET RECOVERY FULL
ALTER DATABASE [testNewDB] SET  READ_WRITE
ALTER DATABASE [testNewDB] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF
```

There are more so I believe the trigger is sending the info for each configuration parameter of the new db created, any idea how to receive only the info of the new DB created without all the rest?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `ALTER_DATABASE` with `CREATE_DATABASE`, but this will not catch a restore event because a restore does not generate a DLL event.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ddl_trig_database]
ON ALL SERVER
FOR CREATE_DATABASE
AS
```

The following article covers a solution that will work around the missing DDL event:

> DDL triggers enable us to audit DDL changes but there are a few
>   missing events, design decisions and installation complications. This
>   post explains and provides a full solution that includes auditing for
>   database restores (there is no DDL event for this) and an incremental
>   self install, which keeps the whole server audit configured for DDL
>   auditing.

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/sql-2008-ddl-auditing-a-full-self-installingupdating-solution-for-whole-server

The solution in the article for RESTORE events involves a job that runs to check for new databases:

> SQL 2008 Audit RESTORE DATABASE
>
> SQL Agent job which runs (in less than 1 second) every 1 minute to
>   copy new restore database auditing information from
>   msdb.dbo.restorehistory to dbadata.dbo.ServerAudit. If it finds that a
>   database restore has happened but has not been audited it
>   automatically runs the “Setup DDL Audit” job because there is a
>   possibility that the restored database is not configured for DDL
>   auditing as expected.

Comment: If I create a new DB, it works with CREATE_DATABASE, if I take a backup and I create another DB from that backup, it doesn't work, that's why I use ALTER_DATABASE

Comment: I've updated the answer with a link that solves your issue -- it seems a bit overly complicated, but specifically mentions that it solves your issues of no DDL for RESTORE events.

Comment: thank you but there must be something easier, I was able to do it on 2014 but for some reason is not working well on 2017